# git rebase command in Android Studio

Tags: git, rebase

I am trying to edit author name of commiter inside **Android Studio** terminal:

`> git log`

```
D:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\ex4_android_fly>git log
commit e4877c673dc89a716c964ea958355573f789628e (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 99849c3 fd3eab5
Author: Devy <devy-example@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jun 23 20:57:49 2019 +0300
```

`> git rebase -i e4877c673dc89a716c964ea958355573f789628e`

```
noop

# Rebase e4877c6..99849c3 onto e4877c6 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
```

All this last text shows in terminal now and I don't know what to do, I want to execute the command `git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`

I mean it seems that I'm stuck with this text message and don't know how to procced to execute the next git command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the author on the last commit you can use :
`git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`

Else you should use :
`git rebase -i origin/master`

## In the rebase list, replace 'pick' with 'edit' (or 'e') for each commit you want to change.

Git will rebase, stopping at each commit you marked. Now do this for each commit you marked:

- git commit --amend --author="author name "
- git rebase --continue

Answer (score 1):

You are using interactive mode of `git rebase` command (`-i`).

Just press `Ctrl`+`C`, then execute the next command.